# How do I check response of a Logic App endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying out Azure Logic apps now and I somehow managed to create a Logic app workflow and now I have exposed my Logic app as an endpoint. How can I monitor the response of the endpoint?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution I provided below helps your problem ? If it works, could you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance. If still have problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-a-response-action) action in your logic app, it can response the value which you want. You can use it to response the body of the request(as the document shows), or the parameters of the request, or the header, or anything else(such as a variable or hardcode string in the your logic app) which you want. After that, when you request the endpoint of the logic app, you can get the response result.
[image]

[image]